# Easiest way to return a custom ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST) with custom message?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, response-entity

This is the first time I develop a REST API with Spring Boot. I want to return a custom message when I have a Bad Request 400 error.

I have my controller:

```
@GetMapping("/DetailDossier/{id},{parameters}/")
public ResponseEntity<List<DetailDossierRspn>> DetailDossierQstn(
        @PathVariable(value = "id") String[] id, @PathVariable(value = "parameters") String parameters,
         throws ParseException {
    List<DetailDossierRspn> rspn = new ArrayList<>();

    WSDetailDossierService mainDAO = new WSDetailDossierService();

// If Sql result return -> List<DetailDossierRspn>

// If no sql result return null

    rspn = mainDAO.initialiserDAO(identifiant, coetb, null);
    if (rspn == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    } else {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(rspn);
    }
}
```

I want the easiest way to return a 400 error:

```java
ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
```

with a custom message.

I tried to create a @ControllerAdvice, but it didn't work because my my controller return a List<Object>

Is there a way to easily create a custom message?

Comment: `ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus. BAD_REQUEST).body("Custom Message");` should do

Comment: Thanks for the comment @HariHaravelan, the problem is i use an List<Object> return, but it work now ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a custom [`@ControllerAdvice`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html):

> **Specialization of @Component for classes that declare @ExceptionHandler**, @InitBinder, or @ModelAttribute **methods to be shared across multiple @Controller classes**.

extending [`ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.html):

> **A convenient base class for @ControllerAdvice** classes **that** wish to **provide centralized exception handling** across all @RequestMapping methods through @ExceptionHandler methods.

Basically something like:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleHttpMessageNotReadable(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex, HttpHeaders headers, HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("my custom message", status);
    }

}
```